# Is it possible to have different port for different environment (region) in Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, ember-cli, angular-cli

I am migrating Angular 2 application(which uses Webpack) to **Angular 4 (with CLI)**.

We have regions *Localhost(Windev),Dev,UAT,SIT and Prod*.

**Now I have requirement to have different port for each environment.**

I am deploying same application on same server for environment **SIT** and **UAT**,So need to have different port.

But I don't know how to this in CLI as I am new to this.

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  defaults: {
    "serve": {
      "port": 3000
    }   
  } 
};
```

Can we do something like this ? have different port in each environment file.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend angular-cli as a production tool to serve your application, instead you can simply serve it using a classic apache. Configuring your vhosts to serve a different version of the application based on the port you're listening on.

Comment: You are right Supamiu, This is how we are doing currently in prod, SIT and UAT.  But we have dev and localhost, there we may need different port.

Comment: For dev environment you're supposed to have one dev environment per dev because they host it locally, so they just need to call ng serve to start their local dev server. your "dev" seems more like a "preproduction" environment, which should be exactly configured like production but not available to external users.

Comment: Yes Supamiu, Agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not use the Angular-CLI embedded webserver for serving other environments besides local development.
The reason is that for acceptance testing you want to reproduce the production environment as closely as possible. Since you would use a real webserver (nginx, apache, iis, ...) in the production environment, you need to replicate this in the other stages as well. (The Angular CLI webserver is not suited for production use, one of the reasons is scalability.)
You can either use different ports or paths to map to document roots to serve the environments when using the same server. Configuration depends on the webserver you are going to use.
If you need to start on a different port anyway, you can use

`ng serve --port 4201`

to use port 4201 instead of the default port.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, this is simple thing , I didn't thought about it, even I saw it earlier,now I realized it, we can then execute same command on different environment with different argument.